# SQL - update now() data with only date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

i have an SQL database with a field which is filled by now() function.

i want to update the present data only with date part of it.

Example :

Present Data :

```
 20.08.2015 13:10:31
 21.08.2015 14:00:29
 22.08.2015 05:55:42
```

Target

```
20.08.2015 
21.08.2015
22.08.2015
```

thanks,

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? Formatting syntax and functions can differ by platform

Comment: What data type is your column

Comment: You can query out the already-existing data without altering the table structure.

Comment: data type is **datetime**

Comment: On select from there you can use trunc(date)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the MySQL database, you can use [date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function

```
update yourtable
set yourColumnName = date(yourColumnName)
```

In SQL Server try using the [Convert function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
update yourtable
set yourColumnName =CONVERT(date, yourColumnName)
```

or

```
update yourtable
set yourColumnName CONVERT(varchar(10),yourColumnName,104)
```

or else you can use the `LEFT` function like

```
update yourtable
set yourColumnName =LEFT (yourColumnName, 10)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1c06/317)**

Comment: @UmutK:- Updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is in a table, you would do something like:

```
update t
    set col = cast(col as date);
```

The exact syntax for converting to a date varies by database.  It might also be:

- date(col)
- date_trunc('day', col)
- trunc(col)

Comment: Removed the last `date(col)` since it was ambiguous